# Converting Image to Bytes and back

Tags: c#

I know there is a lot of help already about this subject, but using this help I ran into a problem: I have an image list with icons that I display in a tree view on a windows form and that works.

Now I want to take these icons, put them in a table, clear the image list and then load the image list from the table.  This is to test if I can use a table to maintain the icons.

The problem is that the icons display a black background using this method. I use `BytesFromImage` to write to an `Image` column in the table and `ImageFromStream` and `StreamFromBytes` to read the data back to an image.

What am I missing?

```
public static byte[] BytesFromImage(Image TheImage)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    TheImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

public static Stream StreamFromBytes(byte[] DataBytes)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.Write(DataBytes, 0, DataBytes.Length);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return stream;
}

public static Image ImageFromStream(Stream DataStream)
{
    return Bitmap.FromStream(DataStream);
}
```

Comment: Can you try some other imageformat?

Comment: Just a sidenote: avoid memory leaks and dispose your streams as soon as possible, preferably using `using` blocks. In your case that would be inside your `BitesFromImage` method and perhaps also inside a possible `ImageFromBytes` method (not included in your code).

Comment: Why do you call `Bitmap.FromStream` instead of `Image.FromStream`?

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's nothing wrong with your code. The problem is format specification. I have run into this problem when i was trying to convert an image which I created from Photoshop with a format of PNG to JPEG/JPG. According to popular documentation like [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/types-of-bitmaps), PNG images retain high detail of information of an image, JPG doesn't. JPEG is not good as a compression option when you want to compress images that have high transitional borders. Especially when porting from PNG to JPEG. You'll always notice that. I think the problem is that you are using a raw bitmap. Try parsing it to `Image` instead of `Bitmap` and see if this works

```
Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually did that in the beginning, but got sidetracked because of the wrong format before that in BytesFromImage.

Answer (score 1):

The black background is caused by converting the icons into the format **GIF**. Better use **PNG**, this should respect transparent backgrounds:

```
public static byte[] BytesFromImage(Image TheImage)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    TheImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around and changing the format to png solved the problem.  Sorry for the unnecessary post.